# Why is my question a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, specific-question

I asked a question ([flask Testing endpoint with session data. The call has no session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55500672/flask-testing-endpoint-with-session-data-the-call-has-no-session)) about following flask's instructions in their manual and it still not working.

It can be seen in the question that I had already applied what is marked as the solution to the duplicated question.
I've tried to think and understand but I'm really failing to see what else do I need to add to make it clear enough they are actually different questions.
In mine, I follow the manual and it's not working, in the linked duplicate, (s)he needed to know how to do it.

Comment: Have you edited your question to address the dupe-closure, and explain how you researched the other Q&A and how it's not appropriate? That should be your first step if your question is closed (or voted to be closed) as a duplicate (and you disagree with the vote/closure), IMO.

Comment: @yivi I tried. That's why I did one edit (and then an edit to fix a mistake I did) which added more code to show the client creation.

Answer (score 26):

I marked it as a duplicate because I felt it was a duplicate. You were asking why your code didn't work. The duplicate was asking how to do what you wanted to do, which necessarily provides working code in the answer. The answer demonstrated that the code to do it was different than the code you used. Of the three relevant lines of code (which look almost identical to yours), your indentation was different from both the answer and the documentation, and the answer explicitly calls out indentation twice.

Given that it was only a few lines of code, I considered that this should be closed as a typo, but decided the duplicate was more useful. Now another user has commented with an even more exact duplicate, and your question remains a typo, but I can't close it again, so someone else will need to.

Comment: I am that user that commented, and I must admit, the dupe you linked to the answer looked to be the same (again, don't know phyton or flask) so I can see the confusion/questioning your decision, but with your edit to the answer it's now perfectly clear

Comment: @davidism The new duplicate link shows the mistake I did. Thank you.